# Are there any connections between James–Stein estimator and quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, soft-question, quantum-information, quantum-interpretations, estimation

Very nice statement from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%E2%80%93Stein_estimator#Interpretation):

> *When three or more unrelated parameters are measured, their total MSE can be reduced by using a combined estimator such as the James–Stein estimator; whereas when each parameter is estimated separately, the least squares (LS) estimator is admissible.*

So I wonder if it offers any new interpretation for distinction between micro(lot of quantum phenomenons) and macro(where everything seems to be defined "more precisely" when "looking at the object as a whole") world.

Comment: Googling for "quantum james-stein estimator", http://www.google.com/search?q=quantum+james-stein+estimator, gives an indication that at least some statisticians and physicists have spent time thinking about the applicability of James-Stein estimation to situations in which there are incompatible measurements. My presentiment is that measurement incompatibility is installed into QT at such a low level that it's unlikely that a relatively high level result such as James-Stein will make a fundamental difference.